# Сложности с клиентом REST API(Не отправляет данные)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

```
    interface PostInt {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("registrate")
    fun Dayu(@Field("phone") phone: String,
             @Field("login") login: String,
             @Field("password") password: String,
             @Field("passwordRepeat") passwordRepeat: String): Call<String>
```

```
class RegistrationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var MessageToMe:TextView
private lateinit var editText1: EditText
private lateinit var editText2: EditText
private lateinit var editText3: EditText
private lateinit var editText4: EditText
private lateinit var editText5: EditText
private var BaseUrl = "http://23.100.28.78/api/"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

    MessageToMe = findViewById(R.id.RTextView)
    editText1 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit1)
    editText2 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit2)
    editText3 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit3)
    editText4 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit4)
    editText5 = findViewById(R.id.RTextEdit5)

    findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton1).setOnClickListener{postData()}

    findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton2).setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    })

}
internal fun postData(){
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(PostInt::class.java)
    val call = service.Dayu(
        phone = editText2.toString(),
        login = editText3.toString(),
        password = editText4.toString(),
        passwordRepeat = editText5.toString()
    )

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        //Ошибка: Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member
        //public abstract fun onFailure(p0: Call<String>!>!,p1:Throwable!):Unit defined in retrofit2.Callback
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<RegistrClass>, t: Throwable) {
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<RegistrClass>, response: Response<RegistrClass>) {
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                val RegistrClass = response.body()!!

                val stringBuilder = RegistrClass.FIO
                MessageToMe!!.text = stringBuilder
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Выведите в лог что у вас в onResponse и в onFailure приходит - возможно там есть описание ошибки и методы её решения.

Comment: Из-за ошибки, которая выведена комментом, я не могу запустить чтобы вывести лог, или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Попробуйте конструктор добавить: `object : Callback<RegistrClass>()`

Comment: Уже пробовал :(

Comment: А вообще структура правильная? Ибо я только вчера начал изучать библиотеку эту.

Comment: Вроде бы всё верно. Кроме того, что у вас путаница с типами. Тип того, что возвращает метод должен совпадать с типами, используемыми в колбэке. Если метод возвращает строку, то её надо везде в колбэке указывать вместо RegistrClass

Comment: Ну и обычно создание экземпляра интерфейса делают синглтоном, который делают с помощью либы для DI, и прикручивают ещё асинхронную либу типа RxJava (или корутины или LiveData). Ещё всю логику на несколькими слоями абстрации прячут (например в презентер-интерактор-репозиторий), но да, можно и без этого, хотя DI и Rx лично я считаю настолько удобными, что они просто необходимы)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Не подскажете источники где я могу все это посмотреть, пожалуйста?)

Comment: Я не знаю таких источников) Наверное можно просто любые статейки с примерами по помянутым технологиям посмотреть...

Comment: Попутно, введенный повторно пароль нет смысла передавать на сервер, он обычно лишь для того, чтобы проверить нет ли ошибок или опечаток при первом вводе. Проверку надо производить на клиенте перед отправкой на сервер.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja Проверка будет с обоих сторон, сейчас первоочередное разобраться из-за чего возникает ошибка